# Using get() to retrieve unique key from Google Firebase in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I am using react componentDidMount() to get() data from a google firebase database.

How can I access the unique id/keys from the response that are assigned to them after pushing data?

```
componentDidMount () {
        console.log( this.props );
        // const {match: {params}}=this.props;
        axios.get( 'https://blog-6d4da-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/posts.json' )
            .then( response => {
                const posts = Object.values(response.data);
                const updatedPosts = posts.map( post => {
                    return {
                        ...post,
                        author: 'Max'
                    }
                } );
                this.setState( { posts: updatedPosts } );
                
            } )
            .catch( error => {
                console.log( error );
                
            } );
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Object.keys(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: i got it with Object.keys(response.data) Thanks!